# Is there a way to check if a certificate is client cert or server cert?

Tags: certificate, handshake, jks

I received a new keystore .jks file for ssl connection to replace an old, but working, .jks  keystore file, but I got "unexpected handshake message: serve_hello" error. I was told to make sure the keystore contains a client cert, so I used keytool to export its cert to a pem file, then use openssl to check the purpose. The result shows

Certificate purposes:
SSL client : No
SSL client CA : No
SSL server : Yes
SSL server CA : No
...

However when I applied the same process to check the old but working jks file I got the same result. Wonder if this is the right way to verify the certificate? And how to troubleshooting this handshake error with the new jks file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [extended key usage](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12) extension contains OIDs which define the purpose:

> id-kp-serverAuth             OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 1 }
> -- TLS WWW server authentication
> -- Key usage bits that may be consistent: digitalSignature,
> -- keyEncipherment or keyAgreement
>
> id-kp-clientAuth             OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 2 }
> -- TLS WWW client authentication
> -- Key usage bits that may be consistent: digitalSignature
> -- and/or keyAgreement
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280 Page 44

See: https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 and https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2

When opening a certificate on Windows you can see the extension here:

[image: Client Auth Certificate]

[image: Server Auth Certificate]